# Does anyone know any examples that use this function or can write a simple example oneself?

Tags: grammar, questions

I wrote the following question:

> **Does** anyone **know** any examples that use this function or **can** write a simple example oneself?

This question uses "does" and "can" to ask about knowing or ability (to write such an example). I'm not sure about the correct way to use "does" and "can" in a single question. Could you please tell me whether my question is correct or not?

By the way, I'm also not sure about oneself - maybe it must be themselves?

Answer (score 1):

`Does... know` is grammatically correct, but `Does... can write` is not. One way this could be corrected is by changing the subordinate clause to independent:

`Does anyone know any examples that use this function, or can anyone write a simple example oneself?`

It could also be rewritten as:

`Can anyone provide an example of the use of this function or write a simple one?`

This keeps verb usage in parallel; i.e. `Can... provide` and `Can... write`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @DrMoishe Pippik's answer regarding verb usage.

With respect to "oneself" vs. "themselves," I would go with "themselves" or even "themself." I think "oneself" can only be used as a reflexive pronoun where the pronoun "one" is used, or where no other pronoun is used but "one" is understood, e.g. (from https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oneself)

> > It is important **[for one]** to have good feelings about oneself.

To me, using "oneself" with any other pronoun (even if it contains the word "one") sounds off. Using the sentence from above as an example:

> It is important **for anyone** to have good feelings about oneself.
>
> vs.
>
> It is important **for anyone** to have good feelings about themself.
>
> It is important **for someone** to have good feelings about oneself.
>
> vs.
>
> It is important **for someone** to have good feelings about themself.
>
> It is important **for a person** to have good feelings about oneself.
>
> vs.
>
> It is important **for a person** to have good feelings about themself.

In all of these examples, I think "themself" (or maybe "themselves," plural) sounds more correct than "oneself."